# Understanding multiple table join with aggregation

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

I have a basic question on how `JOIN` works on multiple tables. I want to count occurrences of Foreign Key in `link1` & `link2`

```
CREATE TABLE main (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE link1 (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   main_id integer NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT main_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (main_id) REFERENCES main (id)
);

-- link2 is similar to link1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e0b1/2)

Why does the query below give a product of counts (rather than sum) when the count is non-zero in both columns.

```
SELECT main.id, COUNT(link1.main_id) + COUNT(link2.main_id)
FROM main
LEFT JOIN link1 ON main.id=link1.main_id
LEFT JOIN link2 ON main.id=link2.main_id
GROUP BY main.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer it myself. Consider a `LEFT JOIN` between `main` & `link1`. The output would be

```
main.id   link1.main_id
   1          1
   1          1
   2          2
   3         NULL  
   4         NULL
```

Now do a `LEFT JOIN` of the above table with `link2`, output would be:

```
main.id    link1.main_id    link2.main_id
   1             1               NULL  
   1             1               NULL  
   2             2                2
   2             2                2     -- Error : double counting for link1
   3            NULL              3
   4            NULL
```

Now count the occurrences of `main_id` & sum them (grouped by `main.id`)

```
main.id        Count
   1             2
   2             2 + 2  
   3             1
   4             0
```

So two successive `LEFT JOIN` are happening sequentially rather than in parallel. The correct approach to get the count would be do conduct 2 queries separately and then add the results

**Update**
Another way according to @a1ex07 is

```
SELECT main.id, COUNT(DISTINCT link1.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT link2.id)
FROM main
LEFT JOIN link1 ON main.id=link1.main_id
LEFT JOIN link2 ON main.id=link2.main_id
GROUP BY main.id
```

Comment: You seem to confuse 0 with `NULL` . The first 2 outputs won't have any zeros. `link1.main_id` and `link2.main_id` might be either equals to `main.id` or `NULL`. And why not just `COUNT(DISTINCT link1.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT link2.id)` ?

Comment: @a1ex07 Thanks for pointing out about `NULL`. I'll update the answer. Regarding `DISTINCT`, I want the count to reflect multiple entries in any table.

Comment: I believe `distinct` will do that (note, it's counting distinct link1.id and link2.id, not link1.main_id/ link2.main_id ). Thus, in your example for main.id = 2  there will be 1 distinct link1.id and 2 distinct link2.id...

Comment: Right, updated the answer. Cool technique.

Comment: @a1ex07: While `DISTINCT` does the trick here, it's a bit like putting lipstick on a pig ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : Nothing tricking about approach with `distinct`. It gives correct result, as well as other solutions like yours or mentioned in the links you provided. Performance-wise `distinct` might behave worse, but I'm not absolutely sure about it without seeing real tests with real data.

Comment: @a1ex07: I have been running many performance tests over the past few years. For small tables it doesn't matter much - because nothing matters much with small tables (except for the worst atrocities). The (limited) `CROSS JOIN` between rows in `link1` and `link2` has a cost characteristic of `O(N²)`, which can be catastrophic for big tables (with many combinations). The additional separate `DISTINCT` steps aren't cheap either. I'll look for a related answer with benchmarks ...

Comment: Related answer with benchmark on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350686/combine-results-of-joins-on-two-tables/11351593#11351593. Also consider the discussion in the comments under the second answer by Gordon: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11351033/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: It seems to me that there is a big difference between this question and links in your comment . The latter doesn't give optimizer any choice but perform cross join and then filter out duplicates to satisfy distinct. In the former I'd expect optimizer to generate the same plan as for your query .

Comment: @a1ex07: I suppose you run a benchmark then and see for yourself. It's the same basic principle.

Comment: It's not the same for those 2 particular queries. I'm not arguing logical stages, but physical order can be completely different.

Answer (score 8):

What you see is a "proxy cross join". Aggregate first, then join:

```
SELECT m.id, COALESCE(l1.ct, 0) + COALESCE(l2.ct, 0) AS total_ct
FROM   main m
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT main_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   link1
   GROUP  BY main_id
   ) l1 ON l1.main_id = m.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT main_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   link2
   GROUP  BY main_id
   ) l2 ON l2.main_id = m.id
ORDER BY m.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8e0b1/5)

Do ***not*** multiply rows with multiple unqualified joins and `count(DISTINCT ...)` later to fix the mistake. It happens to work in this case since counting DISTINCT `link1.id` / `link2.id` coincides with the desired result, but it's **needlessly expensive** and error prone.

Detailed explanation and a couple of syntax variants in these related answers on SO:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626358/939860)
- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

Comment: This has a better performance & works well for my usecase. It should be the accepted answer