# Convert right side of join of many to many into array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.4, array

When using join on many to many relationship the result is split on multiple rows. What I'd like to do is convert the right side of a join into an array so the result is one row.

Example with 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id    serial primary key,
  title text
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  id    serial primary key,
  title text
);

CREATE TABLE items_tags (
  item_id int references items(id),
  tag_id  int references tags(id),
  primary key (item_id, tag_id)
);
```

When selecting items with their tags I can do it this way:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.title
FROM items i
INNER JOIN items_tags it
ON it.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN tags t
ON t.id = it.tag_id;
```

And the result will come up as:

```
(1, "item n1", "sport")
(1, "item n1", "soccer")
(2, "item n2", "adventure")
(2, "item n2", "mountain climbing")
(2, "item n2", "sport")
(2, "item n2", "nature")
```

What I'd like to have is this:

```
(1, "item n1", ["sport", "soccer"])
(2, "item n2", ["adventure", "mountain climbing", "sport" , "nature"])
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### To aggregate most rows

While querying all or most items, it is typically substantially faster to aggregate rows from the "many"-table first and join later:

```
SELECT id, i.title AS item_title, t.tag_array
FROM   items      i
JOIN  (  -- or LEFT JOIN ?
   SELECT it.item_id AS id, array_agg(t.title) AS tag_array
   FROM   items_tags it
   JOIN   tags       t  ON t.id = it.tag_id
   GROUP  BY it.item_id
   ) t USING (id);
```

Use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` in the outer query if there can be items without tags - which would be excluded with `[INNER] JOIN`.

Since that does not multiply rows in the join, we need no `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

Joining *before* aggregation also gets out of hands with more than one 1:n table in the `FROM` list (not in this simple case). See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

#### To aggregate few rows

```
For a small percentage of rows, use a [`LATERAL`][2] join with an [ARRAY constructor][3]:

SELECT id, title AS item_title, t.tag_array
FROM   items i, LATERAL (  -- this is an implicit CROSS JOIN
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT t.title
      FROM   items_tags it
      JOIN   tags       t  ON t.id = it.tag_id
      WHERE  it.item_id = i.id
      ) AS tag_array
   ) t;
```

Since an ARRAY constructor always produces a row (with empty array if the subquery is empty - subtle difference in the result!), `LEFT JOIN LATERAL (...) ON true` is not needed here. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)
- [Understanding multiple table join with aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/understanding-multiple-table-join-with-aggregation/87479#87479)

#### Aside

You had a typo in your query. 3rd column would be `t.title`. I added aliases to your original (un-aggregated) query to clarify:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title AS item_title, t.title AS tag_title
FROM   items      i
JOIN   items_tags it ON it.item_id = i.id
JOIN   tags       t  ON t.id = it.tag_id;
```

"id" or "title" are poor identifiers. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

Comment: i found it helpful to see these working:
op sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/710a3/3/0 and aggregate join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/710a3/4/0

Comment: also something similar to postgrest many:many join table maps (https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#many-to-many-relationships). 
 this keeps the items list even if there are no tags (left outer join) and uses empty array instead of null: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f94e3/4/0.

Answer (score 21):

You need to add the `group by` clause and use `array_agg`.

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, array_agg(i.title)
FROM items i
INNER JOIN items_tags it
ON it.item_id = i.id
INNER JOIN tags t
ON t.id = it.tag_id
GROUP BY i.id, i.title,
```