# Convert right side of join of many to many into array of objects

Tags: postgresql, join, array

I have 2 tables:

Table `subjects`: `id, class_id, title, created_at, updated_at`
Table `marks`: `id, student_id, class_id, mark, created_at, updated_at, subject_id`

I want to query subjects table and have it return all of its columns and also marks column, that is of type array (and the values in it are supposed to be objects) that has essentially the result of the query

```
select * from marks where marks.subject_id = subjects.id;
```

So a result row looks something like this:

```
 (5,3,"Subject 1","2022-01-25T12:05:11.000Z","2022-01-25T12:05:11.000Z"
, [{id:15, student_id:12, class_id:3, mark:5, created_at:"2022-01-23T12:05:11.000Z", updated_at:"2022-01-23T12:05:11.000Z", subject_id:5}
 , {id:23, student_id:12, class_id:3, mark:5, created_at:"2022-01-21T12:05:11.000Z", updated_at:"2022-01-21T12:05:11.000Z", subject_id:5}
  ])
```

The question is similar to [Convert right side of join of many to many into array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173831/convert-right-side-of-join-of-many-to-many-into-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution depends on missing details. A plain correlated subquery is one of various options (especially good for small selections).
Using [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) to aggregate rows into an array of objects:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT json_agg(m.*) FROM marks m WHERE m.subject_id = s.id) AS marks
FROM   subjects s;
```

To use only a subset of columns, see:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)

Comment: I just tried this and it works great, I'm guessing it's speed is optimized?

Comment: @Mihael: Depends on whether you select most or few  rows. But it won't get much faster.

Comment: Thanks so much @Erwin, just one more question, is it possible to do it nested way, so something like `SELECT *, (SELECT json_agg(u.*, (SELECT json_agg(m.*) FROM marks m) AS marks) FROM students u) AS students FROM subjects s;` I tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: Using the link you provided I came up with this `SELECT *, (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id', u.id, 'user_id', u.user_id, 'class_id', u.class_id, 'marks', (SELECT json_agg(m.*) FROM marks m))) FROM students u) AS students FROM subjects s;` and it works, but I would like to not have to write every column name, because I do need all of them, but I'm fine with this but if there is a better option, that would be awesome.
Thanks

Comment: @Mihael: I think your last query is incorrect (missing `WHERE` clause to link marks to students), and I think it can be simplified. But both is hard without an actual test case and the precise expected result. Crate a new question with the specifics, be sure to add your version of Postgres and a fiddle - random example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ad9a3a7c0f49e399d4efc0f933e83a45