# how to use distinct on to avoid aggregating column in this query?

Tags: postgresql, query, subquery

what I am trying to do is I want to calculate the quantity for the `inventory` the formula for that is `receive_order_entries.quantity`+ the sum of all `inventory_transactions.quantity` for that inventory

my current approach are like below but it has problem with grouping and aggregating

how to avoid using aggregate or group by for each column that I select in this query?

I know the column is should be aggregated or grouped by since `inventory` has many `inventory transactions`

I have read about `distinct on` from postgres sql but I don't know how to use it
I have tried to add `DISTINCT ON (inventories.id,receive_order_entries.product_id)` after `select` but
it still gives the same error messages

`the error messages`

```
ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

`my db schema from rails`

```
# in rails every table automatically
 has autoincrement bigint id for primary key, and datetime for created_at

create_table "receive_order_entries", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "product_id", null: false
  t.datetime "expiry_date"
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nama", default: "", null: false
end

create_table "inventories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "receive_order_entry_id", null: false
  t.decimal "harga_jual", default: "0.0", null: false
end

create_table "inventory_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "inventory_id", null: false
  t.string "type"
  t.integer "quantity", default: 0, null: false
end
```

`my current sql syntax`

```
select inventories.id, products.id as product_id, receive_order_entries.id as receive_order_entry_id,
products.nama,
receive_order_entries.expiry_date,
inventories.harga_jual,
sum(receive_order_entries.quantity + 
   COALESCE((SELECT SUM(case 
        when inventory_transactions.type = 'DecrementInventoryTransaction' then -(inventory_transactions.quantity)
        when inventory_transactions.type = 'IncrementInventoryTransaction' then inventory_transactions.quantity
        else 0 end
    ) 
        FROM inventory_transactions
        WHERE inventory_transactions.inventory_id = inventories.id
        and not inventory_transactions.approved_at is NULL
        and not inventory_transactions.approved_by_id is NULL),0)
   ) as qty
from inventories 
inner join receive_order_entries 
on inventories.id = receive_order_entries.id 
inner join products
on receive_order_entries.product_id = products.id 
group by inventories.id, products.id, receive_order_entries.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in for a couple of inconsistencies in the question, this should do it:

```
SELECT i.id, r.product_id, i.receive_order_entry_id, p.nama, r.expiry_date, i.harga_jual
     , r.quantity + it.qty AS qty
FROM   inventories i
JOIN   receive_order_entries r ON r.id = i.receive_order_entry_id
JOIN   products              p ON p.id = r.product_id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT inventory_id
        , COALESCE(sum(quantity) FILTER (WHERE type = 'IncrementInventoryTransaction'), 0)
        - COALESCE(sum(quantity) FILTER (WHERE type = 'DecrementInventoryTransaction'), 0) AS qty
   FROM   inventory_transactions
   WHERE  approved_at IS NOT NULL
   AND    approved_by_id IS NOT NULL
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) it ON it.inventory_id = i.id;
```

The point is to aggregate quantities from `inventory_transactions` in a subquery *before* joining to it. That's also the fastest way while processing the whole or most of the table. For a small selection use a `LATERAL` subquery instead. See:

- [Convert right side of join of many to many into array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173831/convert-right-side-of-join-of-many-to-many-into-array/173879#173879)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

Comment: I've update my question with my own working solutions have you any thoughts for that?

Comment: hi I've update my question with my own working solutions with  `group by inventories.id, products.id, receive_order_entries.id`,  you seems experience any thoughts about ur solutions vs using `group by` ?

Comment: @joyoy: Hard to say. Depends on the exact table definitions and cardinalities. (`receive_order_entries.quantity` does not even show in your schema, and I see no FK constraints) Typically, my query is the fastest option.