# How to give precedence to rows from one table over matching rows in another?

Tags: postgresql

I've got `(key, value)` pairs stored in two different tables - `company_settings` and `branch_settings`. A `key` can exist in none, one or both of the tables.

In case the `key` exists in both tables, I'd like to use the `value` stored in the `branch_settings` table. Otherwise, if available, I'd like to fall back to the `value` stored in the `company_settings` table.

```
company_settings
-------------------------
| key    | value
-------------------------
| key.A  | 4             |
-------------------------
| key.B  | 5             |
-------------------------


branch_settings
-------------------------
| key    | value
-------------------------
| key.A  | 1             |
-------------------------
```

So, if I query for `key.A` the result should be `1` since `key.A` exists in both tables and I want to give higher precedence to records from `branch_settings` table.

If I query for `key.B` the result should be `5` since `key.B` exists only in `company_settings` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the value for only one `"key"`, you can use `COALESCE()` function with 2 subqueries:

```
-- query 1a
SELECT COALESCE(
           (SELECT value FROM branch_settings WHERE key = prm.key),
           (SELECT value FROM company_settings WHERE key = prm.key)
       ) AS value 
FROM
    (VALUES ('key.A')) AS prm (key) ;
```

You could also expand the list of keys inside the `VALUES`, to search more than one key:

```
-- query 1b
FROM
    (VALUES ('key.A'), ('key.B'), ..., ('key.Z')) AS prm (key) ;
```

If you want to search many keys however, it might be more efficient to convert the subqueries to joins. Either two `LEFT` joins:

```
-- query 2
SELECT prm.key, COALESCE(b.value, c.value) AS value 
FROM
    (VALUES ('key.A'), ('key.B'), ..., ('key.Z')) AS prm (key)
  LEFT JOIN branch_settings AS b ON b.key = prm.key
  LEFT JOIN company_settings AS c ON c.key = prm.key ;
```

or a `FULL JOIN`, similar to @James' answer:

```
-- query 3
SELECT key, COALESCE(b.value, c.value) AS value 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM branch_settings 
     WHERE key IN ('key.A', 'key.B', ..., 'key.Z')
    ) AS b
  FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM company_settings 
     WHERE key IN ('key.A', 'key.B', ..., 'key.Z')
    ) AS b
  USING (key) ;
```

There is a subtle difference between queries 1b, 2 and query 3. The last query will give you in the results only the (parameter) keys that appear in at least one of the tables. Query 1b and 2 will have all the (parameter) keys in the results, with `NULL` in `value` for keys that can'e be found in either table.

Comment: `COALESCE ` is brilliant. However, I don't understand what `(VALUES ('key.A')) AS prm (key)` is doing?

Comment: It's just a way to pass the parameter once (so it isn't in the two WHERE clauses). You could also expand the list of keys inside the VALUES, to more than one.

Comment: If you only need 1 row, won't the `JOIN` be just as efficient as the subqueries? In which case, I'd favor the improved readability and flexibility of the `JOIN`.

Comment: is it possible to know which table `COALESCE` matched in ?

Comment: @user2616355  yes, you could have a `CASE` expression in the SELECT list or a simple check, eg: `SELECT ..., (b.value IS NOT NULL) AS value_comes_from_b ...`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ would it be possible to have a full query or dbfiddle, I was trying and could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in any RDBMS (only with the assumption that branch keys appear in company table, with is not correct, see comments and below):

```
SELECT cs.key AS key, 
       CASE WHEN bs.key IS NULL THEN cs.value ELSE bs.value END AS value
FROM company_settings AS cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN branch_settings AS bs ON (cs.key=bs.key)
WHERE cs.key='whatever'
```

Also, if you are still on design stage, have a look at PostgreSQL inheritance here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-inherit.html .
Be wary of the various drawbacks detailed, but otherwise your use case could be a good fit to it.

**EDIT** taking into account that a branch key may not appear at all in the company settings key, this would be better suited:

```
SELECT key, value FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS p, key, value FROM branch_settings WHERE key='whatever'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS p, key, value FROM company_settings WHERE key='whatever'
) AS merge
ORDER BY p ASC
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cs.key IS NULL THEN bs.key ELSE cs.key END AS key,
       CASE WHEN bs.key IS NULL THEN cs.value ELSE bs.value END AS value
FROM company_settings AS cs
FULL OUTER JOIN branch_settings AS bs ON (cs.key=bs.key)
WHERE bs.key='whatever' OR cs.key='whatever';
```

And here is an example of using inheritance in this case (may probably not be the smarter way, it works better in the first assumption above)

```
test=# CREATE TABLE company_settings (key text, value text, pos int DEFAULT 1);
CREATE TABLE
test=# CREATE TABLE branch_settings (pos int DEFAULT 2) INHERITS (company_settings);
NOTICE:  merging column "pos" with inherited definition
CREATE TABLE
test=# INSERT INTO company_settings VALUES ('A', 4);
INSERT 0 1
test=# INSERT INTO company_settings VALUES ('B', 5);
INSERT 0 1
test=# INSERT INTO branch_settings VALUES ('C', 6);
INSERT 0 1
test=# INSERT INTO branch_settings VALUES ('A', 1);
INSERT 0 1
test=# SELECT key, value FROM company_settings WHERE key='A' ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 1;
 key | value
-----+-------
 A   | 1
(1 row)

test=# SELECT key, value FROM company_settings WHERE key='B' ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 1;
 key | value
-----+-------
 B   | 5
(1 row)

test=# SELECT key, value FROM company_settings WHERE key='C' ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 1;
 key | value
-----+-------
 C   | 6
(1 row)

test=# SELECT key, value FROM company_settings WHERE key='D' ORDER BY pos DESC LIMIT 1;
 key | value
-----+-------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thanks for the example using `inheritance`. So, a key can exist in both the tables. We define precedence using the `pos` field. Very bright, indeed. I may not use it for storing `key-value` pairs, but it gives me an idea about something else I'm working on. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

#### For a *single* `key` value

> So, if I query for `key.A` ...

Sounds like you typically query for a *single* key value. The simplest and fastest way to do this has not been posted, yet:

```
             SELECT value FROM branch_settings  WHERE key = 'key.A'
   UNION ALL SELECT value FROM company_settings WHERE key = 'key.A'
-- UNION ALL SELECT 0  -- optional default (with matching type!)
   LIMIT 1;
```

Postgres will stop executing as soon as the first row is found. Testing with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, you'll see `(never executed)` for the second query if the first query returns a row.

The third `SELECT` is totally optional, but a cheap and elegant way to default to value if the key is in neither of the two tables.

Note a ***subtle difference*** to using `COALESCE((SELECT ..), (SELECT ..))`: My query returns whatever is found in the column if the row exists - including potential NULL values, which can happen if the column `value` isn't defined `NOT NULL`. `COALESCE`, on the other hand, cannot distinguish between two distinct cases of NULL:

1. The search for 'key.A' returned ***no row***.
2. The search for 'key.A' returned a row but the ***`value` is NULL***.

You may or may not want to lump both cases together. But be aware of the difference.

Related:

- [How to force order of WHERE clauses in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184287/how-to-force-order-of-where-clauses-in-postgresql/184309#184309)

#### For *multiple* `key` values

Nested in a `LATERAL` subquery, the same technique works for any number of values:

```
SELECT k.key, v.value
FROM  (VALUES ('foo'::text), ('bar'), ('baz')) k(key)  -- could be a table or query too
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
             SELECT value FROM branch_settings  WHERE key = k.key
   UNION ALL SELECT value FROM company_settings WHERE key = k.key
   -- UNION ALL SELECT 0
   LIMIT 1
   ) v ON true;
```

In a cursory test, this was ***several* times faster** than `LEFT JOIN` + `COALESCE` for 500 keys. It reduces work for Postgres to a minimum.

`LEFT JOIN LATERAL (...) ON true` retains `key` values without match (which can only happen without the commented last `SELECT`). To drop such rows instead:

```
SELECT k.key, v.value
FROM   k, LATERAL (
             SELECT value FROM branch_settings  WHERE key = k.key
   UNION ALL SELECT value FROM company_settings WHERE key = k.key
   LIMIT 1
   ) v;
```

You still get NULL in `value` for actual NULL values in `branch_settings.value` or `company_settings.value`. Adapt the query to handle distinct cases any way you need.

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)
- [Understanding multiple table join with aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/understanding-multiple-table-join-with-aggregation/87479#87479)

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server (probably, but not always the same as postgresql - for example, I had to use key_' and not 'key'), I'd try this:

```
select isnull(b.key_,c.key_) as key_, isnull(b.value, c.value) as value
from branch_settings b
full outer join company_settings c on b.key_ = c.key_ ;
```

I tested it like so:

```
create table company_settings (key_ varchar(255), value int) ;
create table branch_settings (key_ varchar(255), value int) ;

insert into company_settings (key_, value)
values
('Key.A',4),
('Key.B',5) ;

Insert into branch_settings (key_, value)
values ('Key.A',1) ;

select isnull(b.key_,c.key_) as key_, isnull(b.value, c.value) as value
from branch_settings b
full outer join company_settings c on b.key_ = c.key_ ;
```

And my results were

```
key_    value
Key.A   1
Key.B   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are three more options... take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/39beb/9) to see them in action.

**1. FULL OUTER JOIN**

I find this the most elegant and sane. Performance is probably the best as well, but table/index size among lots of other factors will impact performance. The join may cost you more than other options, but I may choose this anyway.

```
SELECT
  key,
  coalesce(branch_settings.value, company_settings.value)
FROM
  company_settings
  FULL OUTER JOIN branch_settings USING (key);
```

Bonus, you can add your parameters in a single `WHERE` clause like any other query.

```
WHERE
  key = 'key.A' -- single
  OR key IN ('key.A', 'key.B', ..., 'key.Z') -- several
```

**2. DISTINCT ON ...**

This option works well and has the added benefit of removing the full outer join at the expense of adding the `DISTINCT ON` clause... not free, but may be better given other factors.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (
    key
  )
  key,
  value
FROM
  (
    SELECT 1 AS priority, key, value FROM branch_settings
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS priority, key, value FROM company_settings
  ) AS "sub"
ORDER BY
  key,
  priority;
```

**3. COMBINING QUERIES**

Depending on how often you have `branch_settings` overriding `company_setting` this could also be a viable option. The biggest downside is that it hits both tables twice. That said, if the second request is relatively limited it could be a viable option.

```
SELECT
  key,
  value
FROM
  branch_settings
UNION ALL
SELECT
  key,
  value
FROM
  (
    SELECT key FROM company_settings
    EXCEPT
    SELECT key FROM branch_settings
  ) AS "sub"
  JOIN company_settings USING (key);
```