# JOIN tables and return count even if it is 0

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, count, postgresql-9.6

I have this query:

```
select settings.customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms, from settings
join (select customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms from settings) as res on res.customer_id=settings.customer_id
where res.alarms is not null;
```

which returns

```
+------------------+
|customer_id|alarms|
|1          |{...} |
|2          |{...} |
|3          |{...} |
+------------------+
```

Then I have another entity `registration`, which fields `customer_id` and `date`, where `date` is of type `date` and I store the values in format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

What I want to achieve is to join the `registration` entity on `customer_id` and get a count on the `registration` records for a given single date, f.e. `'2018-11-20'`. But (here's the catchy part) I want to retrieve it in a way so if there are no registration records for the date, then return 0, otherwise return the actual number.

With the solutions I've tried so far, I would get only records that have the `alarms` AND have registrations as well, as if I have this:

```
select settings.customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms, coalesce(regs.count, 0) from settings
join (select customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms from settings) as res on res.customer_id=settings.customer_id
join (select customer_id, count(customer_id) from registration where date='2018-11-20' group by customer_id) as regs on settings.customer_id=reg.customer_id
where res.alarms is not null;
```

or

```
select settings.customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms, coalesce(count(regs.customer_id), 0) from settings
join (select customer_id, current::jsonb->'alarms' as alarms from settings) as res on res.customer_id=settings.customer_id
join registration as regs on settings.customer_id=regs.customer_id
where res.alarms is not null and regs.date='2018-10-10'
group by settings.customer_id, settings.current;
```

If I would put it in other words: get records which have `alarms` object and also get the number of their registrations for the given date, no matter if its 0 or > 0.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN registration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2) is the key, like ypercube commented.

And you probably don't need the self-join - assuming `settings.customer_id` is `unique not null`.

**If** your predicate is selective (more than a few rows without alarms), I suggest to count in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT s.customer_id, s.current::jsonb->'alarms' AS alarms
     , coalesce(r.reg_ct, 0) AS reg_ct
FROM   settings s
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS reg_ct
   FROM   registration
   WHERE  customer_id = s.customer_id
   AND    date = '2018-10-10'
   ) r ON true
WHERE  s.current::jsonb->'alarms' IS NOT NULL;
```

**Else**, a plain subquery should be faster:

```
SELECT s.customer_id, s.current::jsonb->'alarms' AS alarms
     , coalesce(r.reg_ct, 0) AS reg_ct
FROM   settings s
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT customer_id, count(*) AS reg_ct
   FROM   registration
   WHERE  date = '2018-10-10'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) r USING (customer_id)
WHERE  s.current::jsonb->'alarms' IS NOT NULL;
```

Either way, it's typically faster and less error prone to aggregate *before* the join.
Related:

- [Understanding multiple table join with aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/understanding-multiple-table-join-with-aggregation/87479#87479)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: Woah, thanks for the explanation! :) 
Btw, on the LATERAL query I get `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY`, so I removed the `GROUP BY` and it works. :) And also for me the LATERAL query executes on average 5 times faster than the plain subquery.

Comment: @Milkncookiez: Yes, that `GROUP BY 1` was a code artifact, you did the right thing by just removing it.