# Extract and combine multiple values from a jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, join, json, set-returning-functions, postgresql-12

I am looking to extract multiple values from a jsonb column in Postgres, and am running into an issue where some values are coming back null.

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jfmdnPMe29ZbXibvGEW3Rr/0)

Setting up schema:

```
create table jsonb_test (test jsonb);
insert into jsonb_test values('{
"title": "test",
"tags": [
    {"tag": 1},
    {"tag": 2}
]
}'::jsonb);
```

Query that I am running:

```
select jsonb_path_query(test, '$.title'::jsonpath) as title,
       jsonb_path_query(test, '$.tags.tag'::jsonpath) as tag
from jsonb_test
```

The result that I am looking for should be:

```
| title | tag |
|-------|-----|
| test  | 1   |
| test  | 2   |
```

and what I am getting is:

```
| title | tag |
|-------|-----|
| test  | 1   |
| null  | 2   |
```

For the query, I have tried everything I can think of to make the null go away, selecting the second set of values from a cross join as opposed to the same table, aggregating it into a regular array and then using unnest, etc, but I can't seem to get it to work, and more importantly, I don't understand what is causing that second null.

What is the easiest way (performance is not expected to be an issue here) to get the result that I am looking for?

Comment: Please put all essential code into the question, not just the fiddle - especially not on a fiddle site that requires to run scripts from multiple sites.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Done,

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - what do you mean by `especially not on a fiddle site that requires to run scripts from multiple sites.`? I see db<>fiddle as a Godsend - different servers (even Firebird, for which I have a fondness - SQL in check constraints!) and other features (e.g. [compare](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&rdbms2=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06073f8adae8d59fb89c8a415d4b398f)) - so what's the problem with scripts from multiple sites? I mean, don't most sites run scripts from multiple sites? I do agree with you though that code should be included in the answer as well as in a fiddle!

Comment: @Vérace: I am a fan and supporter of Jack's [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) site from the first day - which works even without activating scripts from third-party sites. The link here is to www.db-fiddle.com - a different site altogether, which does not work without scripts from multiple third-party sites. Aside from that, it's the standing rule here that essential parts of the question must be included on-site,  not just linked to. Links can die quickly.

Comment: Oh, and I do not like running scripts from third-party sites I don't trust. My NoScript prevents that from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) is a set-returning function. When putting more than one of those in a `SELECT` list, this is the expected behavior. See:

- [What is the expected behavior for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)

You seem to be looking for a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM       (SELECT jsonb_path_query(test, '$.title'::jsonpath) AS title FROM jsonb_test) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT jsonb_path_query(test, '$.tags.tag'::jsonpath) AS tag FROM jsonb_test) b
```

Alternatively, and probably more elegantly, use two `LATERAL` joins:

```
SELECT a.title, b.tag
FROM   jsonb_test j
     , jsonb_path_query(j.test, '$.title'::jsonpath) a(title)
     , jsonb_path_query(j.test, '$.tags.tag'::jsonpath) b(tag);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66ef3c1777db02fdbf48ba7c822a8542)*

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Effectively, a "proxy cross join". See:

- [Understanding multiple table join with aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87249/understanding-multiple-table-join-with-aggregation/87479#87479)